# How to use DJI Ronin MX in adverse weather

Tags: video, production

Hi has anyone ever used a DJI Ronin MX in the rain? if so how have you protected it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous simple solutions including shoulder mounted umbrellas and rain shields, or even ones mounted on the Ronin itself.

Obviously, in a complete downpour you may need to consider a waterproof camera bag. These are pretty cheap anyway.